# Upload TSV file in Wordpress is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, file-upload

> I tried uploading TSV file in my wordpress site but it does not work.
>   When I check if the uploaded TSV file is not empty, it appears to be
>   empty. Here's the code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>TSV File</label>
    <input type="file" name="tsv" class="form-control"/>            
</div>
```

> Here's the codes for checking if the TSV file is empty or not.

```
$tsv = $_FILES["tsv"];
if( !empty($tsv) ){
   //process the tsv file 
}else{
   wp_send_json_error("File is empty");
}
```

> It always fall to the empty handler even if the TSV file is not empty.
>   Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, please use the quote formatting for when you actually quote someone or something - and not just to make your own text look “more colorful”. Second: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Your html input name should be an array. `name="tsv[]"`